# Crossed or random effects? (lme4)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I am examining the effects of the type of context change (change in personnel, change in setting) on response rate of a targeted behavior (e.g., aggression) among patients in a treatment center.

There are 30 patients, some of whom experienced only one context change, and some of whom experienced multiple context changes of one or both types. Among all patients, there were a total of 100 context changes.

Responses per minute of the targeted behavior before and after context changes were measured across treatment sessions. For all patients, behavior was recorded for 5 sessions before a context change ("pre-change" phase) and 5 sessions immediately after a context change ("early post-change" phase). For some patients, behavior was recorded for 5 additional sessions ("late post-change" phase; i.e., sessions 6-10 after a context change).

I am analyzing these data using a linear mixed model.

I believe I need to include crossed random effects, given that some patients experienced only one context change type but others experienced both types. However, I am not sure about this. Thus, my first question is whether the following model is specified correctly:

```
model <- lmer(Behavior_Rate ~ Session * Phase * Change_Type + (1|Patient) + (1|Change_Type), data = Data)
```

A related question is regarding the ICC:

```
Formula: Behavior_Rate ~ 1 + (1 | Patient) + (1 | Change_Type)
   Data: Data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  3606.8   3627.1  -1799.4   3598.8     1178 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.9541 -0.3218 -0.1071 -0.0399 15.0885 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 Patient       (Intercept) 0.1170197 0.3421  
 Change_Type   (Intercept) 0.0005244 0.0229  
 Residual                  1.1840950 1.0882  
Number of obs: 1182, groups:  Patient, 30; Change_Type, 2
```

I calculated the ICC as follows:

ICC_Patient<-.34/(.34+.02+1.09)

ICC_Change_Type<-.02/(.34+.02+1.09)

ICC_Patient: 0.234

ICC_Change_Type: 0.014

My second question is: given the low ICC for Change_Type, should I remove Change_Type as a random effect altogether?

i.e., model <- lmer(Behavior_Rate ~ Session * Phase * Change_Type + (1|Patient), data = Data)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have only 2 `Change_Type` so you should not fit random intercepts for this factor.

The ICC is then trivial to calculate, as $ICC_{patient}= \frac{(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_0^2)}{\sigma_o^2}$

where $\sigma_1^2$ is the variance of the random intercepts for patient and $\sigma_0^2$ is the residual variance.

Note that in your calculations you have used standard deviations. This is wrong - you should use variances.